# populating dependent JSF menu not working

Tags: java, jsf

I have a HashMap `availableGovernates`  holding  the key(`id`) and value as a `governate` object
am trying to populate the cities menu based on the choosen governate  , the  value of (`form.governate`)passed  to the function `getGovAvaiableCities` is null when I check but after submitting , `form.governate` is set

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="governates" value="#{form.governate}"
            converter="converter">
            <f:selectItems value="#{data.availableGovernates.entrySet()}"
                var="governate" itemValue="#{governate.value}"
                itemLabel="#{governate.value.name}"></f:selectItems>
            <f:ajax execute="governates" render="cities" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:selectOneMenu id="cities" value="#{form.city}"
            converter="converter">
            <f:selectItems
                value="#{form.getGovAvaiableCities(form.governate).entrySet()}" var="city" 
                itemValue="#{city.value}" itemLabel="#{city.value.name}"></f:selectItems>

        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: What's the scope of your backing bean?

Comment: it's a ViewScoped Bean

Comment: You should post your backing bean here. Why are you passing `form.governate` to `getGovAvaiableCities` within the view? If both are available in the backing bean, there's no need to have that logic in the view